# How to get this c macro working?

Tags: c

Why is the use of the on and off macro creating problems.
I am new to using c macros.
Is the macro declaration correct or is there some other problem with the code.
Please help ??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

#define ONE 1;             //  OR BY   1 [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ] TO insert 1 at LSB position             
#define TWO_FIVE_FOUR 254; // AND BY 254 [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ] TO insert 0 at LSB position

#define on(x) (x|ONE)
#define off(x) (x & TWO_FIVE_FOUR)

int main()
{
    uint8_t a=53;

    printf("\nValue of byte a : %d",a );

    printf("\nValue of byte b : %d",on(a)); //Error

    printf("\nValue of byte c : %d",off(a)); //Error

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error 3 error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: In your `on` and `off` macros, I'd highly recommend you say `(x)|ONE` and `(x) & TWO_FIVE_FOUR`, lest you "call" it like `off(32 | 16)` or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolons from the macro definitions

```
#define ONE 1              //  OR BY   1 [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ] TO insert 1 at LSB position             
#define TWO_FIVE_FOUR 254  // AND BY 254 [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ] TO insert 0 at LSB position
```

Comment: or better, encase them in parens... ONE (1) TWO_FIVE_FOUR (254)

Comment: i have updated the code and removed the semi colon from macro definitions, but still not compiling

Comment: @RAZER, A line and compiler error would help a lot. For the record, it [compiles fine here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6608409f473d01cde863c9493bb48979).

Comment: yes it does compile, but why dosen't it work on visual studio 2010 ?

Comment: @RAZER I just tried it with Visual Studio 2010 and it's working and shows the same output as http://liveworkspace.org/code/6608409f473d01cde863c9493bb48979 without the semicolons in the macros. You are looking at the wrong spot for the error :)

Comment: see the screenshoot here [link](http://www.pixroute.com/ky8i09se927m/Untitled.jpg.html)

Comment: Finally got it working on vs2010 by removing the semi-colons from the end of #define's for ONE and TWO_FIVE_FOUR

Answer (score 3):

You can always check how gcc sees your code after pre-processing macros using the `-E` switch:

```
gcc -E mycode.c
```

and this is the output:

```
printf("\nValue of byte a : %d",a );

printf("\nValue of byte b : %d",(a|1;););

printf("\nValue of byte c : %d",(a & 254;););
```

and it is clear that the `;`s are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ahey, :)

#define is a preprocessor directive, not a C statement

If you include the ; at the end, the preprocessor will stick it in the middle of the code.

The code you wrote translates thus:

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t a=53;

    printf("\nValue of byte a : %d",a );

    printf("\nValue of byte b : %d",(a|1;););

    printf("\nValue of byte c : %d",(a & 254;););

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Simply remove the semi-colons from the macro definitions, and all should work.

Cheers,
J.

Comment: same error after removing semi-colon, using vs 2010  and even with pelles c ide it the same story

Comment: Can you show us the updated code? I'd like to copy-paste it into my VS and see what it says..