# Wrong macros definition casuses "Expected expression" error

Tags: c, macros

I have these macros:

```
#define TRUE 1;
#define FALSE 0;
```

I want to use them in an if condition, for example:

```
if (functionThatReturnsIntZeroOrOne() == FALSE) do_something();
```

but I get such an error message:

```
"Expected expression".
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get this c macro working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200522/how-to-get-this-c-macro-working)

Comment: Macros do text substitution on source code.   So `if (functionThatReturnsIntZeroOrOne() == FALSE )` is seen by the compiler as `if (functionThatReturnsIntZeroOrOne() == 0;)`  (note the semi-colon).   Remove the semi-colons from the macro definitions.

Comment: For bolean you should use the C standard header `stdbool.h`. This provides macros/typedefs for the standard type `_Bool`. Using custom macros if deprecated and should only be used for legacy code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You defined `FALSE` to be `0;`, define it to be `0` (`#define FALSE 0`, without a semicolon). The semicolon is included in the define, so `FALSE` gets replaced with `0;` which puts a semicolon in your if conditional.